# Não consigo inserir dados na tabela do SQLITE3 (NODE.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sqlite3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sempre quando tento adicionar dados a tabela SQLITE aparece esse erro. Alguém me ajuda, pfv. Estou começando no Back-end agora ;-;

```
        const Database = require("../db/config")

        module.exports = {
            async create(req, res){
                const db = await Database()
                const pass = req.body.password
                let roomId

                /* Gera o numero da sala */
                for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                    i == 0 ? roomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString() :
                    roomId += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString()
                }


                /* Inseri a sala no banco */
                await db.run(`INSERT INTO rooms (
                    id,
                    pass
                ) VAlUES (
                    ${parseInt(roomId)},
                    ${pass}
                )`)
                    

                await db.close()

                res.redirect(`/room/${roomId}`)
            }
        }
```

Comment: A mensagem de erro (que você colocou em imagem, mas deveria ter colocado como texto na pergunta) diz que `db` está `undefined`. Pelo visto, `await Database()` não retorna nada. Precisa ver o código desse arquivo.

Comment: Consegui resolver, refiz o meu arquivo de config seguindo a mesma lógica e funcionou. 
Enfim...kkkk vai entender. Mas obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Doutor, baseado no que enviou, não sei como está lá no '../db/config' porém nessa parte de código que enviou, faltou fazer o require como por exemplo abaixo.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

const db = new sqlite3.Database('./database.sqlite', (error) => {
  if (error) console.log(error);
});
```

isso foi feito dentro do '../db/config'?? creio que tenha que trazer o chamado aqui pra seu arquivo principal e deixar apenas a configuração como caminho... senha... nesse arquivo separado.

O que o erro está te falando é que não reconhece esse .run() ou seja, não deu certo o seu require

Comment: coloquei o config abaixo , obrigado p está tentando me ajudar :)

Comment: mas então @gabrielReis, ele não ta conseguindo puxar o require lá de dentro do arquivo, taca tudo em um arquivo só pra ver se passa entende?